# How to have callbacks in useState

Tags: reactjs

My component looks like this:

```
constMyComponent = props => {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
       getData(id).then(function(myEvents){
           setEvents(myEvents);
       });
   }, [id]);
```

When I render the variable "events" it looks good thanks to the question mark operator:

```
<ul>
{ events && Object.keys(events.events).map( (data, i) => (
        <li key = { i }>
           <span>
              { events.events[data].mykey}
           </span>
        </li>
        ))}
     </ul>
```

However, in "useEffect" I need to apply some logic to the retrieved data. After the row with

```
setEvents(myEvents);
```

I cannot access the variable "events". I guess it is not ready yet. I read a little bit about callback. Is that the way to go?
Just adding a ".then" won't work. How do you usually access data when it is accessible in this case?

Comment: Just keep using `myEvents`; you already *have* the new value, you don't need to wait for `events` to be reassigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i understand ur question correctly u wanna make the new `events` made logically depending on old `events` And wana access it,

U can access it like this,

```
setEvents(prevEvents => {

  // some logical computations

  return theNewEvents
});
```

As of this example,

> ```
> function Counter({initialCount}) {
>  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
>  return (
>    <>
>      Count: {count}
>      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
>      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
>      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
>    </>
>  );
> }
> ```

From [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

> But, if u wanna make the logical changes to the new `events`,
> U can easily do it in the function before setting the state (as @jonrsharpe pointed out)

```
constMyComponent = props => {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
       getData(id).then(function(myEvents){
           // make ur changes to `myEvents`
           ...
           // then, set it to state
           setEvents(myEvents);
       });
   }, [id]);
```